# Autonumbering in Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a question regarding autonumbering in oracle,

so I have a sequence like this,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE WELTESADMIN.NUMBERING
START WITH 0
MAXVALUE 999999999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE NOCACHE NOORDER
```

and my oracle SQL is,

```
$allDrawingSql = "SELECT MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED.*, NUMBERING.NEXTVAL AUTONUMBERING FROM MASTER_DRAWING_ASSIGNED 
                  WHERE SUBCONT_ID = :SUBCONTID AND PROJECT_NAME = :PROJNAME";
```

and the way i show the table is like this,

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($allDrawingparse, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
                 echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>'.$row['AUTONUMBERING'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';}
```

My problem is everytime the variable :SUBCONTID and :PROJNAME changes, my numbering doesnt start from  1. instead I keep seeing the START WITH with the sequences script variable changes.
My intention is everytime i query a table, the numbering start from 1
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want, simply select rownum pseudo column instead of using a sequence.